# Drilling down into JSON Data Arrays Android

Tags: java, android, json

I am having an issue when trying to drill down further into json data to pull out specific key/value pairs. I am simply trying to pull the longtitude/latitude which I figured is a sub array of location which is a sub array of geometry. 
My JSON:

```
results": [
    {
      "address_components": [
        {
          "long_name": "56",
          "short_name": "56",
          "types": [
            "street_number"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "Rosario Drive",
          "short_name": "Rosario Dr",
          "types": [
            "route"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "Waterbury",
          "short_name": "Waterbury",
          "types": [
            "locality",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "New Haven",
          "short_name": "New Haven",
          "types": [
            "administrative_area_level_2",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "Connecticut",
          "short_name": "CT",
          "types": [
            "administrative_area_level_1",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "United States",
          "short_name": "US",
          "types": [
            "country",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "06708",
          "short_name": "06708",
          "types": [
            "postal_code"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "formatted_address": "56 Rosario Drive, Waterbury, CT 06708, USA",
      "geometry": {
        "bounds": {
          "northeast": {
            "lat": 41.5291983,
            "lng": -73.0523455
          },
          "southwest": {
            "lat": 41.5291845,
            "lng": -73.0523456
          }
        },
        "location": {
          "lat": 41.5291845,
          "lng": -73.0523456
        },
        "location_type": "RANGE_INTERPOLATED",
        "viewport": {
          "northeast": {
            "lat": 41.5305403802915,
            "lng": -73.05099656970849
          },
          "southwest": {
            "lat": 41.5278424197085,
            "lng": -73.05369453029151
          }
        }
      },
      "types": [
        "street_address"
      ]
    },
    {
      "address_components": [
        {
          "long_name": "56",
          "short_name": "56",
          "types": [
            "street_number"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "Rosario Drive",
          "short_name": "Rosario Dr",
          "types": [
            "route"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "Woodbridge",
          "short_name": "Woodbridge",
          "types": [
            "sublocality",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "Vaughan",
          "short_name": "Vaughan",
          "types": [
            "locality",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "York Regional Municipality",
          "short_name": "York Regional Municipality",
          "types": [
            "administrative_area_level_2",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "Ontario",
          "short_name": "ON",
          "types": [
            "administrative_area_level_1",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "Canada",
          "short_name": "CA",
          "types": [
            "country",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "L4H",
          "short_name": "L4H",
          "types": [
            "postal_code_prefix",
            "postal_code"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "formatted_address": "56 Rosario Drive, Vaughan, ON L4H, Canada",
      "geometry": {
        "bounds": {
          "northeast": {
            "lat": 43.8324404,
            "lng": -79.5703888
          },
          "southwest": {
            "lat": 43.83244029999999,
            "lng": -79.5704073
          }
        },
        "location": {
          "lat": 43.8324404,
          "lng": -79.5704073
        },
        "location_type": "RANGE_INTERPOLATED",
        "viewport": {
          "northeast": {
            "lat": 43.83378933029149,
            "lng": -79.5690490697085
          },
          "southwest": {
            "lat": 43.8310913697085,
            "lng": -79.57174703029152
          }
        }
      },
      "types": [
        "street_address"
      ]
    },
    {
      "address_components": [
        {
          "long_name": "56",
          "short_name": "56",
          "types": [
            "street_number"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "Rosario Drive",
          "short_name": "Rosario Dr",
          "types": [
            "route"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "Summerville",
          "short_name": "Summerville",
          "types": [
            "locality",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "Dorchester",
          "short_name": "Dorchester",
          "types": [
            "administrative_area_level_2",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "South Carolina",
          "short_name": "SC",
          "types": [
            "administrative_area_level_1",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "United States",
          "short_name": "US",
          "types": [
            "country",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "29483",
          "short_name": "29483",
          "types": [
            "postal_code"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "formatted_address": "56 Rosario Drive, Summerville, SC 29483, USA",
      "geometry": {
        "bounds": {
          "northeast": {
            "lat": 33.0303119,
            "lng": -80.2500213
          },
          "southwest": {
            "lat": 33.0302964,
            "lng": -80.2500223
          }
        },
        "location": {
          "lat": 33.0302964,
          "lng": -80.2500213
        },
        "location_type": "RANGE_INTERPOLATED",
        "viewport": {
          "northeast": {
            "lat": 33.0316531302915,
            "lng": -80.24867281970849
          },
          "southwest": {
            "lat": 33.0289551697085,
            "lng": -80.25137078029151
          }
        }
      },
      "partial_match": true,
      "types": [
        "street_address"
      ]
    },
    {
      "address_components": [
        {
          "long_name": "56",
          "short_name": "56",
          "types": [
            "street_number"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "Rosario Drive",
          "short_name": "Rosario Dr",
          "types": [
            "route"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "Silver Lake",
          "short_name": "Silver Lake",
          "types": [
            "neighborhood",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "Providence",
          "short_name": "Providence",
          "types": [
            "locality",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "Providence",
          "short_name": "Providence",
          "types": [
            "administrative_area_level_2",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "Rhode Island",
          "short_name": "RI",
          "types": [
            "administrative_area_level_1",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "United States",
          "short_name": "US",
          "types": [
            "country",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "02909",
          "short_name": "02909",
          "types": [
            "postal_code"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "formatted_address": "56 Rosario Drive, Providence, RI 02909, USA",
      "geometry": {
        "bounds": {
          "northeast": {
            "lat": 41.8053438,
            "lng": -71.4620833
          },
          "southwest": {
            "lat": 41.8053382,
            "lng": -71.4621001
          }
        },
        "location": {
          "lat": 41.8053382,
          "lng": -71.4620833
        },
        "location_type": "RANGE_INTERPOLATED",
        "viewport": {
          "northeast": {
            "lat": 41.8066899802915,
            "lng": -71.46074271970849
          },
          "southwest": {
            "lat": 41.8039920197085,
            "lng": -71.46344068029151
          }
        }
      },
      "partial_match": true,
      "types": [
        "street_address"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status": "OK"
}
```

My Code:

```
if (response != null)
            {
                JSONObject json;
                try {
                    json = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONObject results = json.getJSONObject("results");
                    JSONArray geometry = results.getJSONArray("geometry");
                    JSONArray location = geometry.getJSONArray("location");




                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
```

Error:

```
On this line:                   JSONArray location = geometry.getJSONArray("location");

The method getJsonArray(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments String.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of your JSON response object is:

"results" is JSONArray which contains 4 JSONObjects.

These JSONObjects contain other JSONObjects, such as

```
"address_components", "formatted_address", "geometry" and "types"
```

You want to get to JSONObjects "lat" and "lng" which are in JSOBObject "location", which in turn is in JSONObject "geometry".

The whole structure then is something like this:

- JSONArray "results"

  - JSONObject [0]

    - JSONObject "address_components"
    - JSONObject "formatted_address"
    - JSONObject "geometry"

      - JSOBObject "location"

        - JSOBObject "lat"    <------- you want this
        - JSOBObject "lng"    <------- and this
  - JSONObject [1]

  etc

To get to lat and lng, you could do:

```
JSONObject json;
    try {
        //create main JSONObject
        json = new JSONObject(response);

        //get results array
        JSONArray results = json.getJSONArray("results");

        //get first JSONObjects in the array
        JSONObject firstObj = results.getJSONObject(0);

        //get JSONObject for key "geometry"
        JSONObject geometry = firstObj.getJSONObject("geometry");

        //get JSONObject for key "location"
        JSONObject location = geometry.getJSONObject("location");

        //get strings for keys "lat" and "lng"
        String lat = location.getString("lat");
        String lng = location.getString("lng");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

To get the remaining lat and lng, just go through all the objects in the array, so:

```
JSONObject firstObj = results.getJSONObject(1);
JSONObject firstObj = results.getJSONObject(2);
JSONObject firstObj = results.getJSONObject(3);
```

By the way, there's missing `{` and `"` at the beginning of your json response. I guess it's just an omission, but you can check if any JSON string is valid at jsonlint.com.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the error:

> The method getJsonArray(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable
>   for the arguments String.

It wants an index (int) but you are providing a Key (String).

Try locating the index of the parameter you're after and passing that in instead.

Or try this:

```
JSONObject geometry = results.getJSONObject("geometry");  
JSONObject location = geometry.getJSONObject("location");
```

Comment: Tried what you said initially and I get 'at results of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject' when ran

Comment: Did you do a .getJSONArray?  Have to change that too.

Comment: Yes it underlines toJsonObject stating "The method toJSONObject(JSonArray) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments ()

Comment: Yea, that was a flase start.  My bad.  I think @Ridcully has it right - geometry isn't actually an array, neither is location.

Comment: Try doing both as getJSONObject and see if that works, ala the new edit.

Comment: Still got the same error as " org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject'" , But its on this line   JSONObject results = json.getJSONObject("results"); - assuming since results is an array? I tried changing the results line to array but then it highlights getJSONObject again with the second error i posted in these comments

Comment: Go back to the original code, and just do get JSONObjects.  I think you might have tweaked something up?  EDIT:  NM, I think you have that right.  results is an array.  YOu can iterate of that array and pull objects from it though.

Comment: No matter what I do I keep getting this now: The method getJSONObject(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments String.

Comment: JSONObject json = new JSONObject(apiURL);
        JSONArray mResults = json.getJSONArray("results");

        Log.i(mTAG, mResults.toString());
        
        JSONObject geometry = mResults.getJSONObject("geometry");  
        JSONObject location = mResults.getJSONObject("location");


This is the new code

Answer (score 1):

The value for the key `geometry` is no JSONArray but a JSONObject (notice the curly braces).
Thus, `getJSONArray()` does not work.

The error message is a bit misleading though.